# Showing two field extensions are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the finite extension $F/K$, [$F:K$]=15. Suppose for some $\gamma\in F$, $F=K(\gamma)$. I want to show that $F=K(\gamma^{2}+1)$.

Since the extension is finite, in particular it is algebraic. Therefore I think as long as I show that both $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{2} +1$ satisfy the same minimal polynomial the conclusion will follow. Is this correct? Also, I do not see the significance that the degree of the extension is playing, I would appreciate a hint about this as well.

Comment: I think you mean "both $\gamma$ and $\gamma^2+1$" in the second paragraph...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, yes thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would be true, indeed, that if $\gamma$ and $\gamma^2+1$  satisfy the same minimal polynomial, then $K(\gamma)\cong K(\gamma^2+1)$ are isomorphic, hence have the same degree over $K$. Since $K(\gamma^2+1)\subseteq K(\gamma)$, the equality of degree would suffice to show equality of fields.

But that is not always the case.  For example, if $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\gamma=\sqrt[15]{2}$, then notice that $\sqrt[15]{4}+1$ does not satisfy the same minimal polynomial as $\gamma$ (neither does $\sqrt[15]{4}$).

Instead, note that $K(\gamma)$ is an extension of $K(\gamma^2+1)$, since $\gamma^2+1\in K(\gamma)$. Now notice that $\gamma$ satisfies the polynomial $x^2 -(\gamma^2+1) +1 \in K(\gamma^2+1)[x]$, so the degree of $K(\gamma)$ over $K(\gamma^2+1)$ is at most $2$. Can it be equal to $2$?

More generally:

> **Proposition.** Let $K$ be a field, and let $u$ be algebraic over $K$. If $[K(u):K]$ is odd, then $K(u)=K(u^2)$.

(I know two proofs: a slick one using Dedekind's Product Theorem, and a direct computational one.)

You can deduce what you want after noting that $K(\gamma^2+1) = K(\gamma^2)$.

Comment: Arturo, I guess that by "Dedekind's Product Theorem" you mean what I know as "The Tower Law". I had never seen that name for it before. Do you have a reference where it is called in that way? Or maybe a history book where the result is attributed to Dedekind?

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: As I recall, there's a book of Stillwell's that attributes it to Dedekind; I'll look it up in my office tomorrow.  (I hope I haven't been misattributing it!) (A friend of mine calls it the "Royal Dutch Airline Theorem",  because he always states it with fields called $K$, $L$, and $M$.)

Comment: Thanks Arturo.  $          $

Comment: Arturo, you don't need to look for it now. I just found it in google books. I found it in Section 5.5 in page 81 of Stillwell's book [Elements of Algebra: Geometry, Numbers, Equations](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=Jw5IYrjui0kC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @AdriánBarquero: Yup, that's the one I was going to check. For a second there, I was afraid I had misremembered and it was attributed to Dirichlet... Glad to know I've been attributing it correctly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you know if this theorem is tight? To prove it we can assume the fields were different, build a minimal polynomial of degree 2 for $u$ over $K(u^2)$ and this contradicts the initial extension being odd.
Can we generalize this to: $[K(u):K]=m$ then $K(u)=K(u^n)$ if $(m,n)=1$?

Comment: @strugglingStudent: Not necessarily, since knowing that $u$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $n$ over $K(u^m)$ doesn't tell you the degree is exactly $m$, just that the degree is *at most* $m$. For $m=2$, you know the degree is either $1$ or $2$ and either will work.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That makes sense. Do you have a specific counterexample on hand?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So if the problem is amongst the divisors of $m$, can we overcome this by requiring $m$ to be prime

Comment: @strugglingStudent No. Again: if $u$ satisfies a polynomual of degree $m$, then its minimal polynomial has degree *at most* $m$. Less than or equal to $m$, not "a divisor of $m$". A primitive cubic root of unity satisfies a polynomial of degree $3$, $x^3-1$, over $\mathbb{Q}$, but has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, even though $3$ is prime.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, you are right. I was confused for a moment. Thanks!